# Prevent router from inserting slashes after hashes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React-Router takes a url of the form:

http://localhost:1234/#home

and converts it to:

http://localhost:1234/#/home

Can I stop this behavior from happening without forking react-router?  I want to keep the URL unchanged: http://localhost:1234/#home

The problem comes from [HashLocation.js](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/0.13.x/modules/locations/HashLocation.js#L28):

```
function ensureSlash() {
  var path = HashLocation.getCurrentPath();

  if (path.charAt(0) === '/')
    return true;

  HashLocation.replace('/' + path);//Kaboom

  return false;
}
```

Not sure why this code is needed.  I tried pulling it out and route navigation broke.  Error:

> Warning: No route matches path "". Make sure you have  somewhere in your routes

I modified my app route:

`<Route name="app" path="" handler={require('./components/app')}>`

**NOTE**

*I need to continue using `hashHistory`.  Switching to another history implementation is not an option due to the fact I'm integrating two different SPA technologies.*

Comment: I switched directions and decided to try a different technology option.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use `browserHistory` and not `hashHistory`.

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

render(
    <Router history={browserHistory} routers={routes}/>,
    document.getElementById('react')
);
```

Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/Histories.md) for more info. I'd also double check your version of `react-router` and upgrade accordingly.

Comment: Updated question.  Sadly this is not an option for me.   Good suggestion though in general.